# "open call hierarchy" in eclipse not working

Tags: eclipse

When I try to use the "Open call hierarchy" function in Eclipse, all of sudden it has stopped working. I don't get any results, it just shows the name of the method I wanted to see the call hierarchy for. This happens for all methods I try, even though they are all called by other methods.

I've tried opening eclipse with -clean -refresh, opening and closing eclipse and the project, updating the project, renaming the .metadata-file, and so far nothing has worked.

I've checked that it searches the whole workspace, and there are no filters on.

Comment: What is the name of the method? I noticed the call hierarchy does not work for common names like `clear()`, `get()`, etc. but don't know why.

Comment: It doesn't work for any method I try it on. For instance logEvent, ackAlarm, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE - Open Call Hierarchy is empty/broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542145/eclipse-ide-open-call-hierarchy-is-empty-broken)

Comment: as specified by @vargapati it is a bug in Eclipse 2019-03

Comment: This happened with me when I configured a new git project on the same workspace and removed the older git project.

Comment: For me it seems to be the issue reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549003 (so the only solution so far seems to remove java 1.8, which I didn't try yet because several projects in that workspace are still using it)

Answer (score 29):

1. Exit Eclipse
2. Go into *Workspace Directory*/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core
3. Delete `savedIndexNames.txt`
4. Delete all *.index
5. Start Eclipse

The search results should now show up.

Comment: Should work, Check if you are deleting the indexes in the workspace you are currently working with, This can be located at <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/. Delete all .index files and savedIndexnames.txt file

Comment: Ensure you're searching for metadata from inside the workspace (if this is not clear)

Comment: Nathan have Suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542145/eclipse-ide-open-call-hierarchy-is-empty-broken, Check if this solution work for you

Comment: 2020 and this is still a thing, as this fix just solved this very problem in my latest version of the IDE.

Comment: It worked but 5th step should be "Start" since we already exited at step 1st. :)

Comment: I remember this once worked. But not anymore... or not with the current screw up of my eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 15):

No need for deleting indexes/re-install eclipse etc.

1. Go to "Call Hierarchy" tab (open by `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `h`)
2. On the upper right corner, there are 2 options:

   1. "Show Caller Hierarchy" (icon, 2 dots directing to 1 dot)
   2. "Show Callee Hierarchy" (icon, 1 dot directing to 2 dots)
3. Change it to "Show Caller Hierarchy"

Comment: mine is at Show Caller Hierarchy AND set to search workspace and not working

Comment: @jonathan Heindl thanks for edit. It was just a typo mistake. That sentence was meant towards me. :-)

Comment: @Dean Hiller: it is a bug in Eclipse 2019-03. (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545293). As it will not be fixed in the 2019-03 version, I updated my Eclipse to the latest available one Integration Build, and it works now.

Comment: Its working thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 3):

Changing Installed JRE to JDK from Windows|Preferences|Java|Installed JREs worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Change Windows|Preferences|Java|Installed JREs, set the default to a JDK.

Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)
Build id: 20210910-1417

Answer (score 1):

Go to window->perspective-> reset perspective.

Comment: Not working and will erase your current perspective. If you try this, save your perspective first for restore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a **search scope** issue. I faced this issue, my eclipse coul'nt find any callers in third projects that uses the method i selected (i also tryed to remove the indexes, restart eclipse, close/open projects, and that was'nt enough so far). I Eventually realized the caller search has a **"Search Scope"** , that can be set to ***current workspace/current Project/working set***. The item "search scope" is in the "call hierarchy" window menu, opened by top-right arrow. I set it to "current workspace" and then it was ok