# error: selected text cannot be mapped to a symbol name & call hierarchy is not working - eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, code-analysis

I had working eclipse workspace and everything was fine. Not sure what went wrong but now I am not able to perform code navigation in eclipse.

I am not able to jump to the definition of the variable or function and getting error:

```
selected text cannot be mapped to a symbol name
```

I am not able to see Call Hierarchy and observing below error:

```
cannot resolve selected text to a defined function or member
```

I need call graph and want to jump to the definition to analyze the code fast.

Tried with some of [SE answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542145/eclipse-ide-open-call-hierarchy-is-empty-broken) which says to perform the below steps.

calling eclipse with **eclipse.exe -clean -refresh** forces Eclipse to
rebuild the index. After that, the feature worked again

The above solution for call hierarchy worked for me once but now not able to make the eclipse up for code navigation. Tried with [other solution](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1090598/) mentioned on internet but not worked.